# Koltin - print 5(or specific Number) random CharRange '0'..'z' and using + Operator to creat one new String

Tags: kotlin, random

I've been doing this Challage and stuck so hard.
Yes, I did find a more easy way but it doesn't fulfill the Challange condition.

Condition:
Create(Print) one String that has 5 or a specific size of Character from a CharRange using + Operator.

little example

```kotlin
fun main() {
   val cRange: CharRange = '0'..'z'
   cRange.random()
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a string with a given length, where each of the characters are randomly selected from a given range?

Comment: Yes, using + Operator

Comment: `val length = 5; val range = '0'..'z'; var output = ""; repeat(length) { output = output + range.random() }`

Comment: i know this function and has using it but never though it can be use this way. Thx you

Comment: is the `+`-operator really a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Functional way to generate string out of random characters

```
val range = 'a'..'z'
val out = generateSequence { range.random() }
    .take(5)
    .fold("") { acc, c -> acc + c }
```

This solution does not need any mutable variable

Comment: instead of the `fold` you may also just want to use `joinToString("")`...

Comment: OP wanted to explicitly use `+` operator . But you are right, `joinToString` would be the ideal way

Comment: no problem... I just returned later to ask that specific question also (see comment on the question), but... no response yet... thought I will leave it here for others...